# Return не возвращает значения объекта

Tags: javascript, node.js, функции, объекты, return

В данном коде возвращается объект :

```js
let obj = {
guild: [Guild],
joinedTimestamp: 1505824699669,
lastMessageID: '765630002858426382',
lastMessageChannelID: '676383769984237578',
premiumSinceTimestamp: 0,
deleted: false,
nickname: null,
_roles: [Array],
user: [User],
options: [Object]
}
async function a (){
return obj
}
a() /* return 
{
guild: [Guild],
joinedTimestamp: 1505824699669,
lastMessageID: '765630002858426382',
lastMessageChannelID: '676383769984237578',
premiumSinceTimestamp: 0,
deleted: false,
nickname: null,
_roles: [Array],
user: [User],
options: [Object]
}
*/
a().joinedTimestamp //return undefined
```

А должно вывести `1505824699669`

Что  здесь не так?

Comment: Посмотрите, что выдаст `console.log(765630002858426382);`

Comment: Точнее всё ок выдало

Comment: Вероятно потому, что число с таким количеством цифр в javascript не может быть представлено как целое.

Comment: Виноват, у вас это строки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
async function a (){
    return obj
}
```

ну так `async` творит чудеса с функциями :)

```
a().then(v => console.log(v.joinedTimestamp));
```

работайте с асинхронными функциями правильно

Comment: Ок,спасибо,протупил :))))

Comment: @KristalkillPlay если ответ вам помог то примите его

Comment: @Danis,мне писал что должно пройти 17 минут,я немного подзабыл за эти 17 минут  :)

Answer (score 1):

```
(async () => {
    console.log((await a()).joinedTimestamp)
})()
```